# SOLVED How to use Metamask with Brownie and Flask

Tags: metamask, brownie, flask

How to:

1. Spin up a front end with brownie
2. Initiate a transaction
3. Have metamask sign the transaction

I have my brownie app connected to my flask app to run the Code of the smart contracts, but i don't want to use a local private key, i want to sign the operation using metamask.

Comment: You can import new private keys into metamask, unassociated with the pneumonic phrase... what is the problem ?